# How do I config sphinx4 for general purpose recognition?

Tags: cmusphinx

I want to use sphinx4 for general purpose voice recognition, e.g. you tell the application something and it prints what you've said. However when I walk through the examples it's all about recognising a very small amount of vocabulary. Is there any good tutorial to help configure it to recognise something more challenging e.g. a dialog between two people?

PS: I believe that sphinx4 already has the correct acoustic models and dictionaries, but the `lm` file is for specific applications, so I'd need a `lm` file, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However when I walk through the examples it's all about recognising with very small amount of vocabulary. Is there any good tutorial to help config it to recognise something more challenging, e.g. a dialog between two people.

You do not need to configure sphinx4. You can just checkout the latest version from subversion and use the demo as is, for more information see the tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

> When I believe is sphinx4 already included the right acoustic models and dictionaries, but the lm file is for the specific applications, so I'm needing a lm file, am I correct?

Default lm file provided is good enough for generic speech, however, if you have specific domain it makes sense to create your domain-specific language model.